# Прописная буква

Tags: грамотная-речь

В нашем районе есть памятники, но почему-то в газете их названия пишут с маленькой буквы: памятник подстаканнику, памятник воинам-интернационалистам. Но ведь это названия и, по-моему, надо с прописной буквы, или же это не названия, а просто кому посвящены.

Answer (score 3):

Слово "памятник" всегда пишется со строчной буквы, памятник чему? - подстаканнику. Это не символ чего-то, сущ. нарицательное, поэтому тоже со строчной.

Памятник кому? воинам-интернационалистам, тоже строчная буква. Если хотите сделать названием, нужно поставить в кавычки, тогда будет с заглавной: памятник "Воинам-интернационалистам", Могила Неизвестного Солдата - тоже памятник, но это и символ, по традиции пишется с большой буквы - из уважения к содержанию, как и Отечество. В обычном смысле со строчной, в символическом - с заглавной.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Памятник подстаканнику - в интернете встречается только со строчной.   Мне не удалось найти написание с прописной. Иначе обстоит дело с другим памятником - памятник  ***Воинам-интернационалистам*** . В первом случае, согласно правилу, с прописной пишется само название, а начальное родовое наименование со строчной. И все со строчной, если имеется в виду посвящение:  ***памятник воином -интернационалистом.*** Именно таких два написание встречается в интернете.

Comment: спасибо Вам